# PyDev doesn't recognise Celery task decorators

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, celery

I'm facing the following issue with my Python/Celery project in  Eclipse/PyDev. 
I've defined my task function in myapp.tasks module like this:

```
@celery.task(max_retries=None)
def mytask(parm1):
    ...
    myapp.myfunction(parm1)
    ...
```

Then, in another module I wish to send a retry signal to the task that's calling the function. So, I do like this:

```
import myapp.tasks
...
def myfunction(parm1):
    ...
    raise myapp.tasks.mytask.retry(countdown=60)
```

By some reason PyDev marks the last line with an error saying: 'Undefined variable from import: retry'
But the code actually works. 
Is this a PyDev issue that doesn't recognize decorators or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Did you install celery after you set up your pydev project (or more precise, your python interpreters)?

Comment: Same issue here with ".delay()". Did you got a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Pydev is apparently using static analysis, which is rather weird for a dynamic language.  But I've added a hack now that should let PyDev successfully statically analyze the celery module.  You can try it out by installing the 3.0 branch:

```
pip install https://github.com/celery/celery/zipball/3.0
```

Comment: I'm running celery 3.0.12 and I still get this error in pydev

Answer (score 0):

PyDev uses static analysis.  You can add a "Forced Builtin" to resolve the error marker.

1. Go to Window -> Preferences
2. Select PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreters in the left pane
3. Select the python interpreter you're using for Celery in the right pane
4. At the bottom, select "Forced Bultins" and click "New..."
5. Add myapp.tasks.mytask or any other types required

In my case, I needed to add "celery.decorators" to resolve a similar error. I'm using Eclipse Neon (4.6.3), but the interface has changed very little.  I've used this technique to resolve errors in Protocol Buffers for several years.